# Redirect does not show component until browser update

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given a condition, when type equals full record, the hooks props.setClient must be true or false depending the userType and setClientType should be equal to userType and then, I must redirect the view, rendendering a new component, which is PersonalInfo

```
const Registro = (props:{setIsReg:any, setClient:any, setClientType:any ,setEmail:any }) => {

//the other code

if(type=="full record"){
    props.setClient(userType=="1"?true:false)
    props.setClientType(userType)

    return(<Redirect push={true} to="/PersonalInfo" />);
    
  }
//some code
```

The condition is executed but the component is not shown until the browser reloads. Why doesn't Redirect reload it automatically and is it necessary to update the browser?

Comment: Where is the `type` variable defined? This will need to either come from props or state to cause the component to re-render when the value is changed. Otherwise you can put it in a useEffect hook to watch for value changes. I can provide an example based on where the variable comes from?

Comment: Thanks but redirect shouldn't it load the component that the url points to?

Comment: Yes but when the component renders if the type variable doesn't equal "full record" the redirect won't occur. Depending on what you mean by "browser update" it suggests that when the component re-renders again the redirect does happen? I'd suggest putting a log inside your if condition to see if it the redirect is being called or not when the component first loads.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly what "browser update" means. But it sounds as though the redirect isn't occurring until the component re-renders. To resolve this you could put the redirect check in a `useEffect` hook which watches the `type` variable. It will run on component mount and every time the `type` variable changes.

```
const history = useHistory()

useEffect(() => {
   if (type === "full record") {
        // include other logic here
        history.push('/PersonalInfo')
    }
}, [type])
```